# Why are the positive measure and negative measure induced by the Hahn Decomposition mutually singular?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The following statement describes the Hahn decomposition and claims that the induced  positive measure and negative measure are mutually singular. Why is that the case?

On a separate note, what are signed measure, Hahn decomposition and Jordan Decomposition good for? I am reading Royden's real analysis and feel a little bit lost.

> **The Hahn Decomposition Theorem**: Let $\nu$ be a signed measure on the measurable space
>   $(X, \mathcal{M})$. Then there is a positive set $A$ for $\nu$ and a negative set $B$ for $\nu$ for which
>   $$X=A\cup B,\quad A\cap B=\emptyset.$$
>
> If $\{A, B\}$ is a Hahn decomposition for $\nu$, then we define two measures $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ with $\nu=\nu^+-\nu^-$ by setting 
>   $$
> \nu^+(E) =\nu(E\cap A),\quad  \nu^-(E) =-\nu(E \cap B).
> $$
>   Two measures $v_1$ and $v_2$ on $(X, \mathcal{M})$ are said to be **mutually singular** 
>   if there are disjoint measurable sets $A$ and $B$ with $X = A \cup B$ for which $v_1(A) = v_2(B) = 0$. The measures $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ defined above are mutually singular.

Comment: Think about the supports of each measure... can a function be both positive and negative at the same?

Comment: As for why this is used, you can break an integral into the difference of two integrals that are both positive (by breaking X into A & B), so to know how to integrate a signed function, one merely needs a theory of integrating positive functions.

Comment: I remember on R, an integral of a function is defined in terms integrals of nonnegative functions. So this is not going to be the case in here? What is the property of R that we do not have in have that make it different?

Comment: This is exactly the case here, you will use your knowledge of integrating non-negative functions, to integrate signed functions. For example, integrate the function that is -1 on (-1,0) and 1 on [0,1). This integral can be written as the difference of two positive integrals as int_(0,1) 1 dx  - int_(-1,0) 1 dx = 1-1 =0

Comment: I guess v+(B) = 0 and v-(A) =0. Is that why they are mutually singular?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to show is $\nu^+(B)=\nu^-(A)=0$. Note that
$$
A\cap B=\emptyset. 
$$
Now one can use the definition of $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$.